# Spring properties configuration using @PropertySource

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration

In the below Spring configuration class, I'm loading app.properties file via @PropertySource and constructing 2 different DBCP data sources using the configurations from the properties file.

Though everything works fine, I don't like declaring a variable for each configuration property with an annotation in order to construct the data source. I tried to autowire Environment class like this

```
@Autowired Environment env;
```

However, when env.getProperty() returns null. Is there a better way to do this?

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class DAOConfig {
    @Value( "${txn.dbhost}" ) private String txnDbHost;
    @Value( "${txn.dbport}" ) private Integer txnDbPort;
    @Value( "${txn.dbservice}" ) private String txnDbService;
    @Value( "${txn.dbuser}" ) private String txnDbUser;
    @Value( "${txn.dbpwd}" ) private String txnDbPwd;

    @Value( "${rpt.dbhost}" ) private String rptDbHost;
    @Value( "${rpt.dbport}" ) private Integer rptDbPort;
    @Value( "${rpt.dbservice}" ) private String rptDbService;
    @Value( "${rpt.dbuser}" ) private String rptDbUser;
    @Value( "${rpt.dbpwd}" ) private String rptDbPwd;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource txnDataSource() {
        return new DataSources.Builder()
                .host(txnDbHost)
                .port(txnDbPort)
                .service(txnDbService)
                .user(txnDbUser)
                .pwd(txnDbPwd)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource rptDataSource() {
        return new DataSources.Builder()
                .host(rptDbHost)
                .port(rptDbPort)
                .service(rptDbService)
                .user(rptDbUser)
                .pwd(rptDbPwd)
                .build();
    }
}
```

**Edit** : I take that back about Environment.getProperty() not working. It indeed works. I was giving property names incorrectly. For those who don't want to use Spring Boot, you could autowire Environment as use it as follows:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class DAOConfig {
    @Autowired Environment env;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource txnDataSource() {
        return new DataSources.Builder()
                .host(env.getProperty("txn.dbhost"))
                .port(env.getProperty("txn.dbport"))
                .service(env.getProperty("txn.dbservice"))
                .user(env.getProperty("txn.dbuser"))
                .pwd(env.getProperty("txn.dbpwd"))
                .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Better how? What are you expecting or hoping for?

Comment: Is there some better way to read properties instead of declaring all those variables with @Value annotations?

Comment: Look at response from @geoand and that is how.

Comment: I still don't get it. You wanted more encapsulation?

Comment: No, basically I do not want to declare those 10 variables with @Value annotation to read the configurations from properties file. With Spring Boot ConfigurationProperties, you can get rid of those 10 lines. This makes the config code much more cleaner and readable. Apologize if I was not clear with my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using (or willing to use) Spring Boot then you can use the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation.

Here is an example from the Spring Boot source code:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.activemq")
public class ActiveMQProperties {

    private String brokerUrl = "tcp://localhost:61616";

    private boolean inMemory = true;

    private boolean pooled = false;

    private String user;

    private String password;

    // Will override brokerURL if inMemory is set to true
    public String getBrokerUrl() {
        if (this.inMemory) {
            return "vm://localhost";
        }
        return this.brokerUrl;
    }

    public void setBrokerUrl(String brokerUrl) {
        this.brokerUrl = brokerUrl;
    }

    public boolean isInMemory() {
        return this.inMemory;
    }

    public void setInMemory(boolean inMemory) {
        this.inMemory = inMemory;
    }

    public boolean isPooled() {
        return this.pooled;
    }

    public void setPooled(boolean pooled) {
        this.pooled = pooled;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Effectively what this does is map the properties `spring.activemq.*` to their respective properties.

Using the previous kind of code spares you from needed to use `@Value` on each field.

For the specific DataSource example you are showing, Spring Boot as of version `1.1.0.M1` provides the `DataSourceBuilder` which build on `@ConfigurationProperties` and vastly simplifies the kind of configuration you are trying to achieve. See the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-a-datasource)

In your case the code would be:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="txn")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="rpt")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting. In my case, I have to configure 2 data sources from properties with prefix "txn.*" and "rpt.*". How do we solve that using Spring Boot ConfigurationProperties?

Comment: @MFIhsan Check my updated answer! Spring Boot also has you covered in the case of multiple datasources :). As you will see from the link, Spring Boot does exactly what you want!