# Spring load application properties in Application listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, encryption

I am trying to listen to application events in Spring and decrypt application properties which are encrypted(has an encrypt prefix). The idea is to create a Spring component that will automatically decrypt spring properties when the environment is loaded if the property value is encrypted.

This needs to work with legacy spring apps(without spring boot) which has application.env.properties files and also the more recent spring boot apps which has properties defined in yaml files.Should be able to decrypt any spring property regardless of the source and should not depend on spring boot and work with any spring version.

```
public class DecryptingPropertiesListener
    implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>, Ordered {
public static final String PREFIX_KEY = "{decrypt}";

private String prefix;
private Encrypter encrypter = Encrypter.defaultInstance();

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event ) {
    Environment environment = event.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment();
    prefix = environment.getProperty(PREFIX_KEY, "{encrypted}");

    final MutablePropertySources propertySources = ((ConfigurableEnvironment) environment).getPropertySources();

    Set<String> encryptedKeys = getKeysOfEncryptedPropertyValues(environment, propertySources);
    addDecryptedValues(environment, propertySources, encryptedKeys);
}

private Set<String> getKeysOfEncryptedPropertyValues(Environment environment, MutablePropertySources propertySources) {
    return streamFromIterator(propertySources.iterator())
            .filter(EnumerablePropertySource.class::isInstance)
            .map(EnumerablePropertySource.class::cast)
            .flatMap(source -> asList(source.getPropertyNames()).stream())
            .filter(this::isNotEncryptionConfigProperty)
            .filter(key -> isEncrypted(environment.getProperty(key)))
            .collect(toSet());
}

private boolean isNotEncryptionConfigProperty(String key) {
    return !PREFIX_KEY.equals(key);
}

private Stream<PropertySource<?>> streamFromIterator(Iterator<PropertySource<?>> iterator) {
    Iterable<PropertySource<?>> iterable = () -> iterator;
    return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
}

private void addDecryptedValues(Environment environment, MutablePropertySources propertySources, Set<String> encryptedKeys) {
    Map<String, Object> decryptedProperties = encryptedKeys.stream()
            .collect(toMap(
                    key -> key,
                    key -> decryptPropertyValue(environment.getProperty(key))));
    propertySources.addFirst(new MapPropertySource("decryptedValues", decryptedProperties));
}

private String decryptPropertyValue(String encryptedPropertyValue) {
    try {
        return encrypter.decryptIfEncrypted(encryptedPropertyValue);
    }
    catch (EncryptionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to decrypt property value '" + encryptedPropertyValue + "'", e);
    }
}

private boolean isEncrypted(Object propertyValue) {
    return propertyValue != null && propertyValue instanceof String && ((String)propertyValue).startsWith(prefix);
}

@Override
public int getOrder() {
    return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
}
```

But the problem is, i don't see the application properties returned on this line, ((ConfigurableEnvironment) environment).getPropertySources();
I can see the system properties here, but not application. Any idea how can i load application properties here and decrypt them?
Thanks

EDIT: Adding a sample properties file. The idea is to add this generic jar as a maven dependency on various webapps, both legacy and new spring boot ones.
The below properties file is of format myapp.env.properties and myapp.system.properties has the env defined. But the spring boot apps use .yaml files. Service and security password needs to be decrypted as they have the prefix.

```
base.url=http://localhost:8080/myapp
service.password={decrypt}123456789==
security.password={decrypt}abcdefgh==
help.email.address=support@gmail.com
```

Comment: Can you share your properties file? It looks like that PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is your best bet. https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring. Check this too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981670/spring-properties-configuration-using-propertysource?rq=1

Comment: Doing this on a `ContextRefreshedEvent` won't work as that is too late, properties are already loaded and applied by then.

Comment: @Kartik Thank you i will look into it, added a properties file. I was hoping listening to events will make it easier to work across legacy spring and newer spring boot apps

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you, can i listen to any other type of event?

Comment: Not really as properties need to be decrypted as soon they are loaded because anything can use them.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks. What do you think is the best approach that works with different propery sources, and across spring versions?

Comment: Depends on how many versions you want to support. But you want either to embed this into the `PlaceholderConfigurer` you are using, by extending it and then configure that, that way it doesn't matter which `PropertySource` is being used. If you really want to wrap the `PropertySource` use an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to wrap the `PropertySource` instances. Or don't build your own solution but use Jasypt which has Spring integration already.

Comment: If the idea is to 'create a Spring component that will automatically decrypt spring properties when the environment is loaded' I might suggests a different more easy to implement approach: You can create a @Decrypt annotation  that depending on the environment will decrypt (or not) the wanted property when its used. I can provide a more detailed example if you think it will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended implementing a custom ApplicationContextInitializer and override the initialize() to decrypt properties from the environment and insert them with high priority so they override the encrypted values.

```
    public class PropertyContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {


       @Override
       public void initialize( ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext ) {
          ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
          for ( PropertySource<?> propertySource : environment.getPropertySources() ) {
             Map<String, Object> propertyOverrides = new LinkedHashMap<>();
// call to decrypt method
             decryptProperty( propertySource, propertyOverrides );
             if ( !propertyOverrides.isEmpty() ) {
                PropertySource<?> decodedProperties = new MapPropertySource( "decrypt " + propertySource.getName(),
                      propertyOverrides );
                environment.getPropertySources().addBefore( propertySource.getName(), decodedProperties );
             }
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and provide instance of `StringEncryptor` and it will handle decryption of properties for you. You can also extend the class to load extra properties if you want.

Example:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyConfiguration {

  @Bean(name="envPropertyConfigurer")
  public EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getConfigurer() {
      return new EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer (encryptor());
  }

  private StringEncryptor encryptor() {
     StandardPBEStringEncryptor s_encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
     s_encryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
     s_encryptor.setPassword("secretKey");
     return s_encryptor;
  }
}
```

you can also do this in spring xml configuration like this

```
<bean id="envPropertyEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
    <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
    <property name="algorithm" value="secretKey" />
</bean>
<bean id="envPropertyConfigurer" class="org.jasypt.spring.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
     <constructor-arg ref="envPropertyEncryptor" />
</bean>
```

You can also read secret key from a file instead of directly setting it here. You can do that by setting StandardPBEStringEncryptor `config` property with `FileStringPBEConfig`.

Comment: Thanks. That class is in jaspyt and we are not using jaspyt and have our own encrypt/decrypt library