# How to make kotlin spring boot app fail if a combination of configuration is present in it's application.yaml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-properties

I am having a microservice which is spring cloud gateway implementation in kotlin.
So as a part of a feature, i need to fail the start-up of this service if I found a specific combination of arguments in the filter configuration present in application.yaml.
To give the filter cofiguration we are using inline notation.
for example:

```
 spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: test1
          predicates:
            - Path=/test1/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/test1/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
            - TLS= OPTIONAL, NONE, TEST
        - id: test2
          predicates:
            - Path=/test2/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/test2/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
            - TLS= MANDATORY, NONE, TEST
```

So in this example configuration, TLS filter is having ags combination as MANDATORY with NONE, then in this case this service should fail at start saying "*MANDATORY with NONE is not a right combination*"

So any suggestion to achieve this ??

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to create an ApplicationEventListener. Basically, you would register one of these listeners to listen to a Spring Boot Event: (One of these: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/package-summary.html)

You can see an example implementation here: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56372260/spring-load-application-properties-in-application-listener`. In that example, properties are being loaded. In your case, I imagine that you could check your properties of interest and throw a RuntimeException if anything violates your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the answer :) but I solved this problem in another way.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do so in kotlin.
Using the init block in class.
https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-init-block-in-kotlin

TLSFilter code which will fail if a specific combination found in the route of that filter

```
class TLSFilter(
    private val filterProperties: TLSFilterProperties,) : GatewayFilter {

private val logger = logger()

init {
    if (filterProperties.mode == DISABLE && (filterProperties.type?.isNotEmpty() == true)) {
        throw IllegalStateException("Security mode `DISABLE` should not be present with any security type in filter configuration.")
    }
    
    if ((filterProperties.mode == MANDATORY || filterProperties.mode == OPTIONAL) && filterProperties.type?.equals(NONE.name) == true) {
        throw IllegalStateException("Security mode = ${filterProperties.mode} with security type = NONE is not a valid configuration.")
    }
}}
```

TLSFilterProperties class which automatically binds with the application.yml file of spring cloud gateway app.

```
  /**
 * Properties that should be initialized in filter configuration properties
 */
class TLSFilterProperties {

    lateinit var mode: SecurityMode
    var type: String? = null
    var alias: String? = null

    companion object {

        val configFieldsOrder = listOf(
                "mode",
                "type",
                "alias"
        )
    }
}
```